# Find data download from Ubuntu bash in windows 10 and vise versa

Tags: bash, windows-10

How can I get data from Ubuntu bash to windows and vice versa. I use putty for ssh connection. How can I reach the private key fro Ubuntu Bash in windows 10 and vise versa. If I download something from the Bash how to reached from Windows 10.

Comment: You might get a better response on SuperUser

Answer (score 2):

On [Windows side](https://askubuntu.com/a/810652/591017) you can just access the files from:

```
%localappdata%\lxss
```

On Linux side:

```
/mnt/c/
```

---

[Server SSH keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76337/where-is-the-ssh-server-fingerprint-generated-stored) would thus be in:

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\etc\ssh
```

and user SSH Keys in:

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\lxss\home\{username}\.ssh
```

*Where **{user}** is your Windows Username and **{username}** is your UNIX Username set during install.*

---

PS. Don't go trying to delete or create files in explorer at the lxss location, that is [REALLY not advised](https://askubuntu.com/a/815948/591017).

[edit]PPS. Great tutorial at https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/5db6/8ee786b7-9fc5-45bf-94d0-16ea91765db6/P488_mid.mp4