# How to use win explorer to create folders for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I use the Windows Explorer to create folders or files in my home directory using "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"?

I tried the following:

1. Enter C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\lxss{username} in the Windows Explorer
2. Create a folder named "scripts" using Windows Explorer
3. Open Bash on Ubuntu on Windows
4. Run `ls -a`

RESULT: total 0

Are there any plans to make something like this work?

P.S. Workaround-ish:

1. I used `mkdir` & `touch` in bash to create folders & files e.g. `scripts/menu.py`
2. I used the Windows Explorer & Notepad++ to edit menu.py
3. I ran the script with `python scripts/menu.py`

Comment: I believe this issue (bash ubuntu on windows) is out of scope of this forum, I suggest you read this [meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15229/do-we-consider-ubuntu-on-windows-10-the-same-as-an-official-ubuntu-flavour-do) about it.

Comment: hi gwarah. i did a cursory perusal of the meta question. it doesn't seem to me like there's concensus on the matter. I wrote this question because i found "http://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice". Also, I just found 9 questions tagged "ubuntu-on-windows" tagged items on this site ("http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows") Love and peace

Comment: Still, you'll probably get a better answer on SuperUser.

Comment: Make some sense what you said @JoeCodeswelluser601770, and maybe could be better discussed on meta, but for what I could understand, while WSL remains on this limbo, questions about this issue should be post on others forums. I pick a Microsoft FAQ: "What is Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)? The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is a new **Windows 10 feature** that enables you to run native Linux command-line tools directly on Windows, alongside your traditional Windows desktop and modern store apps.". And as MS Windows feature I understand be better out of this scope. its MHO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We **STRONGLY recommend against modifying any Linux files/folders from Windows** in the manner described above: Doing so will likely result in data loss and/or corruption:

There's a reason we made the lxss folder hidden and system ;)

It's fine to access Windows from Bash/Linux, but we've not yet done the work to persist and manage Linux file permissions & metadata when accessing files under .../lxss/ using Windows tools & apps.

[2016-11-17: Update]
To expand on this question and its answer, I wrote-up a more thorough explanation here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Rich. I didn't take into account permissions.

Comment: Do any of the Ubuntu text editors like Atom or SublimeText work on Ubuntu on Windows10, or are we stuck with vi?

Comment: We don't support any Linux GUI apps/desktops at this time, although others have had some success getting some GUI/X apps running. Another option is to move your files to Windows under /mnt/c/... and edit from editors running in Windows, but build using Bash.

Comment: Thanks again for another insight, Rich. --> /mnt/c/...  Interesting. Love and peace, -Joe